# how to remove elements from one list if other list contain the indexes of the elements to be removed

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists -
lista = [1,2,3,5,0,5,6,0]
listb = [4,7]

listb contains index numbers.  How can I remove index 4 and 7(contained in lisb) from lista.

I thus want to print new_lista as [1,2,3,5,5,6]

I hope it makes sense.

Alwina

Answer (score 1):

You may try following.

```
for x in sorted(listb,reverse=True): lista.pop(x)
```

Also you may need to make sure that listb does not contain duplicate index and all the index numbers are valid index.

```
for x in sorted(set([y for y in listb if -1 < y < len(lista)]),reverse=True): lista.pop(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`:

```
new_lista = [j for i, j in enumerate(lista) if i not in listb]
```