# Append to a list python based on a second list with multiple rows

Tags: python, list, csv, append

Hypothetically, say I have two lists that have data as follows, and list `A` has multiple rows that I write into a csv via a `for` loop.

```
A = [Date, Round Number, Score, FirstName]
B = [FirstName, Surname]
```

Where every row of `A` is a different round in a sports tournament. List `B` contains every player's `FirstName` and `Surname`. This data is gathered from a GraphQL API query.

There are 100 rows of `A` in the CSV (100 rounds), and List `B` has 20 rows (20 players).

**Question:**
How would I be able to append a player's `Surname` into List `A` after every instance of their `FirstName`?

Disclaimer: I have no background in code, this is my first attempt at a python project.

I've checked out this post but I have not been able to find one without replacing.
[Update list elements based on a second list as index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395945/update-list-elements-based-on-a-second-list-as-index)

Comment: see python   pandas . If you have no coding background then searching is a better option than asking. So use stackoverflow as a searching tool than asking tool. You can ask on Gitter, IRC Freenode, Discord etc if you are a beginner.

Comment: It sound like A And B are lists of lists. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code below will solver your problem:

```
A = [["Date", "Round Number", "Score", "FirstNameA"],
    ["Date", "Round Number", "Score", "FirstNameB"],
    ["Date", "Round Number", "Score", "FirstNameC"]]

B = [["FirstNameC", "SurnameC"],
    ["FirstNameA", "SurnameA"],
    ["FirstNameB", "SurnameB"]]

for round in A:
    for player in B:
        if player[0] == round[-1]:
            round[-1] += " " + player[-1] #Append to last index of round to last index of player

print(A)
```

Output:

```
[['Date', 'Round Number', 'Score', 'FirstNameA SurnameA'], ['Date', 'Round Number', 'Score', 'FirstNameB SurnameB'], ['Date', 'Round Number', 'Score', 'FirstNameC SurnameC']]
```